# Reference a Microsoft Access 2010 Table Value in a VBA Subroutine

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to reference a particular field from a table within a function call.  Specifically, I would like to open an executable and get the path from the table.
Here, the path is hardcoded in:

```
    Shell(“C:\ECLIPSE_CPP\eclipse.exe”)
```

However, I would like to store the path within a table and call a function (maybe the Shell function?) on a path from that table.

This is what I have tried:

```
    strSQL = “SELECT Path FROM Paths WHERE Tool = “”Eclipse””;”
    Shell(strSQL)
```

The Paths table looks like this:

```
 
    Tool    | Path
    ========|=============================

    Eclipse | “C:\ECLIPSE_CPP\eclipse.exe”
```

Does anyone know way to reference this table value in VBA code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strPath = DLookup("Path" , "Paths" , "Tool = 'Eclipse'")
Shell(strPath)
```

`DLookup` is not efficient.  It may be fine for your purpose, but if not, you can use a [recordset](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners) to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim dbs as DAO.Database
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Dim strpath as String

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select Path from Paths where Tool = 'Eclipse'")

strpath = rs.Fields(0)
    '   = rs!Path       alternative
    '   = rs("Path")    alternative

Application.FollowHyperlink(strpath)
```

Comment: Upvote -- nice answer for recordset code, and even an `Application` function.